# How to merge multiple pull requests into different folders?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have multiple pull requests on my GitHub repository. I want to merge all of them into my repo but each one of them into a different folder. I would like to have all the content separated into each folder. Please can anyone help?

Comment: You can clone the repository multiple times in different folders on your machine, and merge them one by one in whichever folder you want.

Comment: Or, clone the repository once, and use `git worktree add`. Be sure you have Git 2.15 or later; if you have 2.5 through 2.14, get everything done within two weeks.